# How to do template tree in PHP?

Tags: php

I use this recursive function to build a tree in PHP:

```
private function getSubscribesTemplate($main = array(), $child = array()) {
    foreach ($main as $key => $val) {
        if($val->SubscrubeToUsersIdNote > 0){
            echo 'Subcategory'. $val->NameCategorysubscribetotype;
        } else {
            echo '<div class="itm">
                    <div class="nav-header nav-header-little">' . $val->NameCategorysubscribetotype . ' | Subscribe</div>
                    <div>// HERE ALL SUBCATEGORIES</div>
                </div>';
        }

        if (isset($child[$val->SubscrubeToUsersType])) {
            $this->getSubscribesTemplate($child[$val->SubscrubeToUsersType], array());
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the result function I need to get an HTML template like this:

```
<div class="itm">
<div class="nav-header nav-header-little">Music | Subscribe</div>
   <div>Jazz</div>
   <div>Rock</div>
   <div>Pop</div>
</div>
```

So to create the parent block with child `<div>`s. What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Fixed grammar and typos.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `if` block:

```
<div>';
// HERE ALL SUBCATEGORIES
if (isset($child[$val->SubscrubeToUsersType])) {
    $this->getSubscribesTemplate($child[$val->SubscrubeToUsersType], array());
} 
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Problem is also that I can notreturn full HTML from function. I dont understand what do you mean in answer

Comment: I need all data that have conditon: `if($val->SubscrubeToUsersIdNote > 0){ $template.= $val->NameCategorysubscribetotype;
}` insert to parent block `class="itm"`

Comment: Simply, insert all child inside parent block. you can show simple example and I will rebuild to my case

Comment: my answer does  that - puts children between <div> and </div>